# Does it make sense to use `ordered_set` for `select` statement with `>` and `<=` for lowering time compexity

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I use ETS table of type `ordered_set`, and row looks like `{{integer_value, string}}` (basically it has no value, only key).

When I perform `ets:select(tab, [match_spec])`, what `match_spec` does is selecting all rows, where `integer_value` meets greater than and lower than comprehensions.

I wonder, do I benefit and instead of scanning whole table, find both lower and upper bounds in logarithmic time and then get all elements in between, like I would expect from SQL table, or such functionality is not implemented in ETS and there is no particular benefit from using `ordered_set` instead of ordinary `set`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is using **timer:tc/3** function for getting execution time of your functions or ets module's functions.
You can profile your code using [**fprof**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/fprof.html) or [**eprof**](http://erlang.org/doc/man/eprof.html) for undestanding what function called and how much time it takes for its execution.
This can help you.
If you are not familiar with erlang profilers, i can show simple example of ets `set` and `ordered_set` with profilers.

Comment: I already discovered (in the topic last updated in 2011 :)) that `ets` scans whole table no matter what, whenever it is sorted set or not. But struggle to get info and 'freshness' of links makes me worry about how alive erlang community and erlang itself today